# Align all the subviews centre to the superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to add four labels programatically using auto layout and align centre to the superview and need to add tableView below of the labels using specific padding. I'm confusing how to align them in centre to the superView[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL6jd.png)

Here is my code:

```
UILabel *lbl = [UILabel new];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl setText:@"Test label1"];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];

UILabel *lbl1 = [UILabel new];
[lbl1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
lbl1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl1 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl1 setText:@"Test label2"];

[self.view addSubview:lbl1];

UILabel *lbl2 = [UILabel new];
[lbl2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
lbl2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl2 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl2 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl2 setText:@"Test label3"];

[self.view addSubview:lbl2];

UILabel *lbl3 = [UILabel new];
[lbl3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
lbl3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl3 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl3 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl3 setText:@"Test label4"];

[self.view addSubview:lbl3];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lbl, lbl1, lbl2, lbl3);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbl(120)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[lbl(120)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbl]-1.0-[lbl1(lbl)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[lbl1(120)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];


[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbl2(120)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[lbl]-1.0-[lbl2(120)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbl2]-1.0-[lbl3(120)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[lbl1]-1.0-[lbl3(120)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

Comment: have a look in http://snapkit.io its a nice lib to manage layout constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a uiview as a container, make your labels subviews of this container view and center the container view within the view - sounds weird, but is actually pretty straight forward :)

```
UIView *containerView = [UIView new];
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

UILabel *lbl = [UILabel new];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl setText:@"Test label1"];
[containerView addSubview:lbl];

UILabel *lbl1 = [UILabel new];
[lbl1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
lbl1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl1 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl1 setText:@"Test label2"];
[containerView addSubview:lbl1];

UILabel *lbl2 = [UILabel new];
[lbl2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
lbl2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl2 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl2 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl2 setText:@"Test label3"];
[containerView addSubview:lbl2];

UILabel *lbl3 = [UILabel new];
[lbl3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
lbl3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[lbl3 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl3 setNumberOfLines:0];
[lbl3 setText:@"Test label4"];
[containerView addSubview:lbl3];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lbl, lbl1, lbl2, lbl3);

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lbl(120)]-[lbl1(120)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[lbl2(120)]-[lbl3(120)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lbl(120)]-[lbl2(120)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lbl1(120)]-[lbl3(120)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

// Update
UITableView *tableView = [UITableView new];
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];

views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView, tableView);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[containerView]-[tableView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

what you get is:
[image: simulator screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! 
But need to add the tableView below the lables

Comment: Need to add the tableView below the lables, but the tableView width must be same as the self.view.frame.size.width